# Variables in <li> names property

Tags: html, laravel

I have li property like this

```
<li name="section_id_1[]">{{$section->title}}</li>
```

but i want variable for 1, something like section_id_.$x.[] like this and $x has any value that change dynamically how i do this

Comment: Can you provide more code? Are you in a foreach loop? You should be able to do something like `"section_id_{{$i}}[]"`.

Comment: thanks, this is the solution for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are in a for loop, you can do something like this

```
<li name="section_id_{{$i}}[]">{{$section->title}}</li>
```

If you are in a foreach loop, I'd suggest simply converting it to a for loop.

---

In Laravel 5.3 (next version of Laravel) you have access to a $loop object in a foreach. This object will contain info about your loop including the index `$loop->index`.